# How can I fit this bottle holder to this bike?

Tags: frames, parts, accessories, bottle

I want to fit this bottle holder on my bike but the attachment seems too thin for the frame tubes. I believe this is a universal bottle holder and my bike isn’t of unusual size or tube girth. Am I missing something here or this just won’t fit?

P. S. Unlike my mountain bike, this bike (Claud Butler Legend) does not have pre-drilled holes for accessories on the frame.

[image: bike bottle holder]

[image: bottle holder and the bike bar]

Comment: There is no "standard" size for bike frame tubing anymore.  Virtually all modern frames have larger tubes than the old classic steel frames.

Comment: That adapter is meant for either the seat tube or other such thinner tubes on bikes which do not have bottle cage bolts. If yours has a quil stem or a think handle bar, or similar, you can try them too. Seat tube might be best bet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not appear to be a attachment for mounting a bottle cage to a frame tube. The two holes in the mount appear to match the two holes in the upper plate of the cage, which orients the mount incorrectly for clamping a frame tube. My guess is that it's for mounting to handlebars - which have a standard diameter, unlike frame tubes.

mounts for frame tubes do exist. They typically use two adjustable straps of some kind to accommodate different size frame tubes. You want something with a beefy strap that can be tightened sufficiently to stop the cage rotating on the frame tube.

Comment: But bottle holder on handle bars? Does anyone even do that?

Comment: Casual riders on upright bikes who don't want to reach down into the frame typically.

Comment: @Neeku - some Eroica riders put their bottles on the steering bar to comply with the respective era looks.

Comment: Some women’s frames don’t have room for a bottle cage

Comment: If I hadn't been using a bar bag I'd have used that mount on my tourer for a camping trip. Instead I fitted bottle holders to the forks. Bottles on bars also works for full suspension mountain bikes (though if you really need full sus you might not want a bottle there).

Comment: Bar mounted bottle on bars of a full sus bike ridden like it should be = water bottle in the face. Real MTBers use CamelBacks, so I'm told.